# SIGTERM not trapped during reboot

Tags: bash, ubuntu

```
$ cat SIGTERM 
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
flag_file=$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)/SIGTERM-TRAPPED
trap 'touch "$flag_file"' SIGTERM
sleep infinity

$ ./SIGTERM &
```

I turned off the computer

[image: I turned off the computer]

After turned on

```
$ test -f "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)/SIGTERM-TRAPPED" || echo "File not found"
File not found
```

Why **File not found** (from which it is understood that SIGTERM is not trapped)?

Comment: ...that said, what's the real-world context here? Generally, if you want to be certain something happens on shutdown, the better approach is to use your process supervision system's facilities for the purpose -- an `ExecStop` hook on modern operating systems that use systemd, f/e. See the related question [How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown] -- having actual dependency control lets you specify that you want your hook run at a specific point in shutdown, f/e, while networking is still up, or while filesystems are still mounted writable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I made some corrections. Read the question again :)

Comment: Anyhow -- this would be a lot more reproducible if you used a `kill` with no reboot. Frankly, nobody else is going to reboot their own machine to try to reproduce a SO bug (and I already explained above why behavior tends to be unpredictable in the reboot case, making different approaches to automating pre-shutdown behavior preferable).

Comment: Another example of how using `reboot` could be throwing this off -- there's no guarantee your program dies by a SIGTERM without being first killed by a SIGHUP when its terminal goes away. So, once again, trusting you'll get a SIGTERM on reboot (much less that you'll get it while filesystems are still writable, your existing file descriptors still valid, &c) is simply unreliable in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I made some updates. Read the question again :)

Comment: `set -e` [is a bad idea. Don't use it.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises)

Comment: ...anyhow, to track down what actually happens in this kind of situation, I personally reach for sysdig (with a systemd service running it that's configured to stay up as far into the shutdown process as possible). That way we don't need to guess what failed, but can actually read and query a trace of every syscall that took place during the shutdown process -- which process received which signal when, and what it did after.

Comment: un esempio di utilizzo (perdona l'ignoranza)?

Comment: Would really need a whole new question on that (and it'd probably be more topical on [unix.se] than here, being a matter of service configuration rather than writing code). Getting it to stay up late into the shutdown process is finicky, and the code I already have for the purpose was written for an employer (so I'd need to redevelop it from scratch using only personal hardware before I had something I could share).

Comment: ok thanks however :)

Comment: Am I correct to understand that the real question is: _How is a script terminated upon reboot or shutdown?_

Comment: Related: [What signal is sent to running programs / scripts on shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/499761/273492) on [unix.se] and [When does the system send a SIGTERM to a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10231/273492) on [unix.se]

Answer (score 1):

First, something like

```
rm -f test/SIGTERM-TRAPPED && ./SIGTERM  & sleep 0.2 && kill -TERM $! && sleep 0.5 && ls test
```

seems like much more convenient way to test this than by rebooting on every attempt.

Now, straces show neither bash nor dash run the trap until the wait for the current command (`sleep infinity`) finishes.

So a process-targetted `SIGTERM` causes the `wait` on `sleep` to fail with `EINTR` (the shell's handler ran, setting a flag that a trap ought to be run later) and the shell `wait`s again. Since the child never finishes, the `wait` never finishes, and the deferred handler never runs.

A process-group targetted `SIGTERM`  (`kill -TERM -$pid` as opposed to `kill -TERM $pid`) would have killed the `sleep` child as well, and the wait syscall in the shell would therefore stop looping, causing the shell to run the trap.

```
 rm -f test/SIGTERM-TRAPPED && ./SIGTERM  & sleep 0.2 && kill -TERM -$! && sleep 0.5 && ls test
```

I think a proper application ought to kill its children when it terminates.

Shells don't do that and instead they rely on process-group-wide kills (`Ctrl+C/Ctrl-\` target the whole foreground process group) or `SIGHUP`s at session ends to take care of their runaway children.

Comment: these considerations are also very useful